# C++ Constant structure member initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, constants

I've a constant `struct timespec` member in my class. How am I supposed to initialize it?

The only crazy idea I got is to derive my own `timespec` and give it a constructor.

Thanks much!

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    private:
        const timespec bar;

    public:
        Foo ( void ) : bar ( 1 , 1 )
        {

        }
};


int main() {
    Foo foo;    
    return 0;
}
```

> Compilation finished with errors: source.cpp: In constructor
>   'Foo::Foo()': source.cpp:9:36: error: no matching function for call to
>   'timespec::timespec(int, int)' source.cpp:9:36: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from sched.h:34:0,
>                    from pthread.h:25,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:41,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:150,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/atomicity.h:34,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from source.cpp:1: time.h:120:8: note: timespec::timespec() time.h:120:8: note:   candidate expects 0
>   arguments, 2 provided time.h:120:8: note: constexpr
>   timespec::timespec(const timespec&) time.h:120:8: note:   candidate
>   expects 1 argument, 2 provided time.h:120:8: note: constexpr
>   timespec::timespec(timespec&&) time.h:120:8: note:   candidate expects
>   1 argument, 2 provided

Comment: Have you tried just initializing it?

Comment: Sure, I did. And I got an error. Edited the question.

Comment: I don't know guys, why you down vote me, but I just couldn't find the correct syntax...

Comment: I mean try something like `const timespec bar = { 0, 0 };`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++11, you can initalise an aggregate member in the constructor's initialiser list:

```
Foo() : bar{1,1} {}
```

In older versions of the language, you would need a factory function:

```
Foo() : bar(make_bar()) {}

static timespec make_bar() {timespec bar = {1,1}; return bar;}
```

Comment: Mike, could you please tell me or throw a good link about how do I use this syntax. Since `bar{1,1} {}`, `bar{1,1}` and `bar({1,1})` work correctly. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: @Kolyunya: `bar{1,1}` and `bar({1,1})` are both correct; the first specifies list-initialisation, while the second specifies direct-initialisation from an initialiser list, which does the same thing. I'd use the first because it's less squiggly, and says more clearly what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use an initialization list with a helper function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdexcept>

class Foo
{
    private:
        const timespec bar;

    public:
        Foo ( void ) : bar ( build_a_timespec() )
        {

        }
    timespec build_a_timespec() {
      timespec t;

      if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("clock_gettime");
      }
      return t;
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo foo;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would make that a `static` (internal linkage) function or even a lambda in C++11 to avoid polluting the class interface.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - Good thought. I'd have made it a private member function if I had been thinking about it. I'd make it a `static` free function only if the initialization is generally unrelated to the class functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Use initialization list

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        const timespec bar;

    public:
        Foo ( void ) :
            bar(100)
        { 

        }
};
```

If you want to initialize structure with bracers then use them

```
Foo ( void ) : bar({1, 2})
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the brace initializer is a C++11 feature.